# How to create Buttons by Foreach ?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to create many button by Foreach,and these Buttons print Uri's Properties. but I don't know how to do it. can you tell me how to do it ?
this is my code:

```
private void CreateButtons()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("/Pages/PageTest.xaml?Name=Stephen&Age=17",UriKind.Relative);

    foreach(var pi in typeof(Uri).GetProperties())
    {
        //create button
        Button btn = new Button();

        btn.Content = pi.Name;

        btn.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,12);

        //i think this is bug, but i don't know,how to do
        btn.Click += (se,ev)=>
        {
           MessageBox.Show(pi.GetValue(btn,null).ToString());
        }

        stackPanel.Children.Add(btn);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Do any of the buttons display? As a guess, you might be creating buttons in the same location, so one is drawn above the others.

Comment: The Ui is correct,I get many buttons, but when i click one of, it's nothing to do ...

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong target for

> pi.GetValue(btn,null)

You are quering URI properties but your target is button object.

You need something like:

```
MessageBox.Show(pi.GetValue(uri, null).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are getting an exception in the event handler.

Try enabling breaking when exceptions are thrown (Debug|Exceptions -> check "Thrown" next to Common Language Runtime Exceptions").

Then run with debugger attached and see what happens when you click a button.  I suspect a NullPointerException

Comment: I know,`MessageBox.Show(pi.GetValue(btn,null).ToString());` isn's run

Comment: Have you tried running as described?  Did you get an exception?